# PHP not returning database item

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to fill a varialble `$login` with the users `user_id` so I can use sessions, however the query does not return the `user_id` to fill the `$login` with.

users.php

```
<?php
function user_exists($username, $con) {
    $data = $username;
    $username = sanitize($data, $con); 
    $username = $data;
    mysqli_query($con, "SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'");
    return(mysqli_affected_rows($con) == 1) ? true : false;
}

function user_active($username, $con) {
    $data = $username;
    $username = sanitize($data, $con); 
    $username = $data;
    mysqli_query($con, "SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `active` = 1");
    return(mysqli_affected_rows($con) == 1) ? true : false;
}

function user_id_from_username ($username, $con) {
    $data = $username;
    $username = sanitize($data, $con); 
    $username = $data;
    mysqli_query($con, "SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'");
    return mysqli_affected_rows($con) ? 0 : 'user_id';
}

function login($username, $password, $con) {
    $user_id = user_id_from_username($username, $con);
    $data = $username;
    $username = sanitize($data, $con); 
    $username = $data;
    $password = md5($password);
    mysqli_query($con, "SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `password` = '$password'");
    return (mysqli_affected_rows($con) == 1) ? $user_id : false;
}
?>
```

login.php

```
<?php
include 'core/init.php';

if (empty($_POST) === false) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if (empty($username) === true || empty($password) === true)  {
        $errors[] = 'You need to enter a username and password';
    } else if (user_exists($username, $con) === false) {
        $errors[] = 'We can\'t find that username. Have you registered?';
    } else if (user_active($username, $con) === false) {
        $errors[] = 'You have not activated your account. Please see the instructions.';
    } else {
        $login = login($username, $password, $con);

        if ($login === false) {
            $errors [] = 'That username and password combination is incorrect;';
        } else {
            echo 'hi';
            die($login);
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $login;
        }
    }

    print_r($errors);
}
?>
```

Init.php

```
<?php 
session_start();
//error_reporting(0);
require 'database/connect.php';
require 'functions/users.php';
require 'functions/general.php';
$errors = array();
?>
```

Comment: @MarkBaker It is, is it not? It's being passed through.

Comment: No, each PHP script needs `session_start` and `session_name` to associate with the current session.

Comment: @Dreamwalker Does my init.php do that? I am not sure. (I have edited the post to contain init.php)

Comment: @Dreamwalker I think you're being fooled by the double-negative in the logic. `empty(...) === false` is identical to `!empty(...)`. It makes my head hurt to visualize it, but they're the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get your userid you are returning the wrong value:

```
function user_id_from_username ($username, $con) {
    $data = $username;
    $username = sanitize($data, $con); 
    $username = $data;
    mysqli_query($con, "SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'");
    return mysqli_affected_rows($con) ? 0 : 'user_id';
}
```

This function will return a 0 (if affected_rows is not 0) or the string 'user_id' (if affected rows is 0). First off I think the logic is probably reversed (0 vs non-zero) and secondly I think you really want to return an actual user_id instead of just the string 'user_id'.

Then in your login function:

```
function login($username, $password, $con) {
    $user_id = user_id_from_username($username, $con);
    $data = $username;
    $username = sanitize($data, $con); 
    $username = $data;
    $password = md5($password);
    mysqli_query($con, "SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `password` = '$password'");
    return (mysqli_affected_rows($con) == 1) ? $user_id : false;
}
```

You get this 0 or 'user_id' (string) into $user_id and then ignore it until the very end when you return either that value or a false. Since the logic was reversed on the return value of the previous function, then on a successful login your $user_id contains the 0 (which is boolean false in PHP) and so this function is returning either a 0 or a false from login - both of them are false so login() is returning false. But specifically in the case of a good login you are returning a 0 which then isn't going to look like a valid ID to put into your session and, if you get it there, isn't going to compare well because of the whole situation of zero being evaluated to boolean false.